# Missing values when using beautiful soap for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract the value from below `html` excerpt:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <td class="rel">
   <div class="ss1 abs lbl_l" style="top:0px;">
    P/E
    <sup>
     4
    </sup>
    <div class="icon-edu icon-general-terms" data-key="P/E Ratio" style="display:none">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;">
    35.520
   </div>
  </td>
 </body>
</html>
```

```py
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(durl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    result = soup.find_all("div", class_="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls")
```

What I got is below. The number 35.520 is missing:

```
[<div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;"></div>,
 <div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;"></div>,
 <div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;"></div>,
 <div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;"></div>]
```

I tried to use another parser like `html.parser`, `lxml`, also same.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `soup.find_all("div", class_="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls")` with your code snippet is returning `[<div class="ss2 abs lbl_r font-num cls" style="top:0px;">35.520</div>]`. Probably the values are inserted via Javascript. Run `print(soup.prettify())` and see if values are there.

Comment: Same here, can not reproduce the issue. I can easily parse the value using BeautifulSoup. Like @AndrejKesely has mentioned, you should try printing your soup object and see if you can see the value in it.

Comment: thank andrej and san, i tested the put as a normal string, beautifulsoap can do the job beautifully. But not if I use requests to get the content dynamically.

Comment: urllib.request.urlopen(www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol=00388)

Comment: in fact, the value required is not in there for the very beginning

Comment: thanks everyone for replying my post. I gave up on this. I found a library using yahoo finance that can do the same with a line of code